# Changing the language according to the local language in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I work in two different **xml** files in different **languages** ​​and these **languages** ​​change according to the phone's native **language**. But when I **switch** to a **different** language in the default language, it still carries the **features** of the **old** **language**. Is there a solution for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should make different layout and var files for each language. You can look at this website: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

Comment: I did this but some places still look old language.what do you think this is about.